# How can a unit test "test the contract" on a method that returns void?

Tags: java, unit-testing, design-by-contract

Java 8 here but this is a general unit testing question that (is likely) language-agnostic.

The syntax of writing a JUnit test is easy, but deciding on *what tests to write* and *how* to test main/production code is what I find to be the biggest challenge. In reading up on unit testing best practices, I keep hearing the same thing over and over again:

> Test the contract

I *believe* the idea there is that unit tests should not be brittle and should not necessarily break if the method's implementation changes. That the method should define a contract of inputs -> results/outcomes and that the tests should aim to verify that contract is being honored. I think.

Let's say I have the following method:

```
public void doFizzOnBuzz(Buzz buzz, boolean isFoobaz) {
    // wsClient is a REST client for a microservice
    Widget widget = wsClient.getWidgetByBuzzId(buzz.getId());

    if(widget.needsFile()) {
        File file = readFileFromFileSystem(buzz.getFile());

        if(isFoobaz) {
            // Do something with the file (doesn't matter what)
        }
    }

    return;
}

private File readFileFromFileSystem(String filename) {
    // Private helper method; implementation doesn't matter here EXCEPT...
    // Any checked exceptions that Java might throw (as a result of working)
    // with the file system are wrapped in a RuntimeException (hence are now
    // unchecked.

    // Reads a file from the file system based on the filename/URI you specify
}
```

So here, we have a method we wish to write unit tests for (`doFizzOnBuzz`). This method:

- Has two parameters, `buzz` and `isFoobaz`
- Uses a class property `wsClient` to make a network/REST call
- Calls a private helper method that not only works with the external file system, but that "swallows" checked exceptions; hence `readFileFromFileSystem` could throw `RuntimeExceptions`

**What kinds of unit tests can we write for this that "test the contract"?**

Validating inputs (`buzz` and `isFoobaz`) are obvious ones; the contract should define what valid values/states for each of those are, and what exceptions/results should occur if they are invalid.

But beyond that, I'm not really sure what the "contract" here would even be, which makes writing tests for it very difficult. So I guess this question really should be something like "*How do I determine what the contract is for a unit test, and then how do you write tests that target the contract and not the implementation?*"

But that title would be too long for a SO question.

Comment: *test the contract* just means given your precondition on the inputs, test that the postcondition of your procedure holds, your example is incomplete in that you didn't give pre- and postconditions for `doFizzOnBuzz`

Comment: The method is not well designed and so it's difficult to test in a reasonable fashion. You've got multiple responsibilities going on here - business logic, 'widget finding' (ie dependency resolution), file reading, and so on. No wonder it's difficult to test.

Comment: Contract testing is done by seeing the method as a blackbox and send all kinds of arguments to the method. It is expected that the method does not run into any undocumented errors. So, in your case, if you send a null Buzz to the method you will face a `NullPointerException` which might violate the contract. If the method declares any throws exceptions, you need to test these also.

Comment: I'd put “define the contract” before “test the contract”. This is actually a good example of how TDD leads to better design. You need to define precise requirements for your methods first, and then proceed from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code with the methods `doFizzOnBuzz(Buzz buzz, boolean isFoobaz)` and `private File readFileFromFileSystem(String filename)` is not easily testable, because the first method will try and read a file, and that's not something you want to do in test.

Here, `doFizzOnBuzz` needs something to provide a File for it to work with. This `FileProvider` (as I'll call it) could be an interface, something like:

```
public interface FileProvider {
  File getFile(String filename);
}
```

When running in production, an implementation to actually read the file from disk is used, but when unit testing `doFizzOnBuzz` a mock implementation of `FileProvider` could be used instead. This returns a mock `File`.

The key point to remember is that when testing `doFizzOnBuzz`, we are **not** testing whatever provides the file, or anything else. We assume that to working correctly. These other bits of code have their own unit tests.

A mocking framework such as [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) can be used a create mock implementations of `FileProvider` and `File`, and to inject the mock `FileProvider` into the class under test, probably using a setter:

```
public void setFileProvider(FileProvider f) {
  this.fileProvider = f;
}
```

Also, I don't know what a `wsClient` is, bit I do know it has a `getWidgetByBuzzId()` method. This class too could be an interface, and for testing purposes the interface would be mocked, and return a mock `Widget`, similar to the FileProvider above.

With mockito, not only can you set up mock implementations of interfaces, you can also define what values are returned when methods are called on that interface: e.g.

```
//setup mock FileProvider
FileProvider fp = Mockito.mock(FileProvider.class);

//Setup mock File for FileProvider to return
File mockFile = Mockito.mock(File.class);
Mockito.when(mockFile.getName()).thenReturn("mockfilename");
//other methods...

//Make mock FileProvider return mock File
Mockito.when(fp.getFile("filename")).thenReturn(mockFile);

ClassUnderTest test = new ClassUnderTest();
test.setFileProvider(fp); //inject mock file provider

//Also set up mocks for Buzz,, Widget, and anything else

//run test
test.doFizzOnBuzz(...)

//verify that FileProvider.getFile() was actually called:
Mockito.verify(fp).getFile("filenane");
```

The above test fails if getFile() was not called with the parameter 'filename'

**Conclusion**
If you cannot directly observe the results of a method, e.g. it is void, you can use Mocking to verify its interaction with other classes and methods.

Comment: In my opinion you should favour stubs implementing the interface over mocks. They make each test more brittle and harder to read.

Comment: I meant more that you should be careful with mocks in tests. Your example uses two mocks but only verifies one. Why not return a stubbed file, that way you don't need to perform misc setups on the file to pass an unrelated test.

Comment: There's also a typo in your verification, you're looking for `"filenane"`. I can't suggest an edit that small though

Comment: Thanks @NickJ, so when, according to Unit Testing Best Practices, is it OK to have `private` methods? Because it sounds like you are (possibly?) advocating removing the private `readFileFromFileSystem` method in lieu of a`FileProvider` interface and respective subclasses. What if a private method is used by multiple methods within the same class - how does this reusable code affect the contracts for those public methods?

Comment: Or perhaps @LukeW might know...?

Comment: @smeeb When it comes to private methods all I see mentioned is that you shouldn't test them as they're an implementation detail which is free to change so long as the public methods (contract) is still functional. In the case of the `readFileFromFileSystem` I'd say that's doing too much to be a private method and should be its own class as suggested per the single responsibility principle.

Comment: I would agree with @LukeW in that `readFileFromFileSystem` is doing too much. Also, you are hard-wiring behaviour. Unit tests should test code in as much isolation as possible, so ideally a unit test would not try and read a file, (or read from a database, or send an http request, or anything else which requires an external resource). As for `private` methods, I suggest keep them for simple repeated interval operations. Of course, you *can* unit tests `private` methods using reflection, but it's not considered good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your contract method does not tell what effect you can observe from the outside. It is basically a BiConsumer, so appart from ensuring there is an exception or not, there is not much unit testing possible.

The test you could do is to ensure that the (Mocked) REST service is called, or that the File (part of the Buzz parameter, which might be pointing to a temporary file) will be impacted by the method under some conditions.

If you want to unit test the output of the method, you may need to refactor to separate the determination of what should be done (file needs update) from actually doing it.